# How to identify a Preference in a Preference Activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-preferences

I have a `ListPreference` that is called by an `Intent`:

```
package com.timeofcubeeliteDYLANFERRIS.cubetimerelite;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    private OnPreferenceChangeListener onPreferenceChangeListener = new
        OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference arg0, Object arg1){
                return true;
        }
    };

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.main_settings);
        Preference p;
        p.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(onPreferenceChangeListener);
    }
}
```

The `Preference p;` is what I'm concerned about. I have the other stuff of finding when it changes, but I don't know how to actually identify the `Preference`. The `Preference` is located in `xml.main_settings.xml`. Its key is `timerIncrement`. Could anyone help me with this?

Summary:
I do not know how to define a `Preference` located in an XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just use `findPreference(CharSequence key)` in order to retrieve the `Preference`.

Answer (score 0):

As you are extending with Preference Activity you directly have `findPreference(CharSequence key)` method to get your preference from your xml file.

So you can define Preference as

```
Preference p = (Preference)findPreference(keyofpreferenceitemyouhavetaken);
```

If it is a EditTextPreference then it would be:

```
EditTextPreference p = (EditTextPreference)findPreference(keyofpreferenceitemyouhavetaken);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below two lines which solves your problem.

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences("sPEICFY YOUR XML LOCATION HERE");
Prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```